# Preciso gerar um relatorio PDF através dessa página, porem quando eu abro window.print(), ele printa tudo, eu queria modificar o que eu desejo printar

Tags: javascript, html5

Software test

```
    <br>
    <br>
    <table class="table col-12" id="tbl">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Cabo</th>
            <th scope="col">Data/Hora</th>
            <th scope="col">Comprimento(m)</th>
            <th scope="col">Resultado</th>
            <th scope="col">Qualificado</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>

          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button type="button" class="btn" style="float: left;" onclick="adicionaLinha('tbl')"> 
        <img src="icons/add.png" width="35px">
      </button>
      <br>
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row col-12">
            <div class="col-5"></div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary col-2" type="button" style="text-align: center;" onclick="CriaPDF()">
                Gerar relatório
            </button>
            <div class="col-5"></div>
          </div>              
      </div>


</body>
```